# How do reset my phone when it won't go past the sercurity check and wont let me type

Tags: factory-reset

[image]

It's not letting my type anything and it's been turned off for a while and this screen is still here

Comment: What happens when you type? The screen isn't responsive or? And if the phone is turned off why's the display still like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the recovery mode to reset the device. To enter recovery mode,power off the device and then hold down the power and volume up key. Then use the volume down button to scroll down to 'wipe data/factory reset' and press the power button. Then, scroll down to 'yes, delete all user data' and press the power button. Finally, after the reset, scroll up to 'reboot system now' and press the power button. After the reboot, your device should be fully reset.
;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use adb of android SDK to reset your phone. Just put your phone on recovery mode and connect it with a USB to your computer and start adb on your system and from there you can do many of things. Just checkout the adb commands and their uses.

Second thing what you can do is put a custom ROM in your phone with help of a Flash tool of your phone and that will give you a new os with Complete fresh functioning in your phone.

Comment: It would be appropriate for you to give the adb commands rather than ask him to check the commands out.

Comment: [link](http://lifehacker.com/the-most-useful-things-you-can-do-with-adb-and-fastboot-1590337225) is the link where you can find useful command for your boot mode of phone.